# Need to fire a call to clickCounter() at page load

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I am using the clickCounter function below:

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount ;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

I can get onclick=clickCounter to work in a button, which shows the counter values in the code below.  However, when the page loads, I can't get the clickCounter() function to fire so that the counter value is shown.

In other words, at page load I need to fire a call to the function so that id="result" has the count values in it.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount ;
</script>

<font face="arial" size="3" color="black"><div>
<span id="result"></span> Downloads
</div></font>
```

Comment: This is definitely not all your code. Are you trying to load value from `localStorage`? Are you storing it there? Try `localStorage.getItem('clickcount');`. This is how it's supposed to work. You should put clickcount to localStorage using `localStorage.setItem('clickcount');`

Comment: I added the clickCounter() function being used into the OP.

Comment: @wrtsvkrfm Are you trying to make this work (I mean the stat counter) for **one user only** or for **multiple users** (so that everybody can see the the total number of downloads)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your javascript after the html tags.

```
<font face="arial" size="3" color="black"><div>
<span id="result"></span> Downloads
</div></font>
<script>
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount ;
</script>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/hxtjLqnq/)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wrap your setting your `.innerHTML` inside of a **[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)** function:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="result"></span> Downloads
</div>
```

In addition to this, the `<font>` tag has been deprecated since HTML 4.0.1, and is both [**obsolete and unsupported**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) in HTML5. Please use CSS for styling instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe is better to use document.onload instead of window.onload in this specific case

Comment: `window.onload` is both better supported and allows [**separation of structure from the action**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/2341603). It's slightly slower to execute, though ensures that everything has loaded. In fact, you'll notice that `document.onload` won't actually show the number at all in the above example :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge from a UX perspective why would you want to watch an empty `(? Downloads)` all the time being a window triggers a loaded state? - Bad bad bad. Everything you have available should be shown to the user - **ASAP!** specially if the element is in viewport or above the fold.

Answer (score 0):

First put that into some function

```
function clickCounter()
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount;
}
```

and than to call it like this

```
<body onload="clickCounter();">
```

or simply you can do it on this way

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- At the time the DOM parser pauses to interpret your `<script>`  tag with
  `document.getElementById("result")....`
  **there's no such `#result` element** in the DOM tree.
  Instead put your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag to make sure all the DOM is read & ready to be manipulated.
- The [`<font>` tg is **obsolete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), use CSS instead.
- Don't use **inline JS** `onclick`. It's bad practice and makes code hard to maintain.
  [Use `Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- In **2018** you should [not care much about **12**+years old browsers IE6, 7](https://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).
- Hope you know that your **counter will work** for **one user only**. Other users will not seee the total number of downloads. For such you'll need a small server-side script to store your counter into Flat-File or into a **database** table.

**Finally:** ([**jsFiddle** live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dc2aydwx/))

**CSS**

```
.text-small { font: 11px/1.4 sans-serif; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <button id="download">DOWNLOAD</button>
  <span class="text-small">
    (<span id="result"></span> Downloads)
  </span>
</div>
```

**JS** (in `<script>` tags right before closing `</body>`)

```
function clickCounter() {
  // Read fron localstorage or fallback to 0
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount || 0;
}

document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function() {
  localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
  clickCounter(); // Do on click 
});

clickCounter();   // and on DOM ready
```

Which is just an improvement of your idea. As mentioned above, a **better way** to do it:

- Store the (+1) number of downloads into your **server-side** database.
- Use `localStorage` just to insert that a specific user downloaded the item.
- Use `localStorage` to not update the database count if the same user clicks more times the download button (prevent fake hits).

Be aware that this can be also **bypassed** by clearing the localStorage and hitting again the Download button - but it's OK for *not-so-tech-savvy* users.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments - looks like there's a lot of deprecated info out there that should be wiped.  So, my bad for using it.  I did notice that the counter is only for one user, so I'll need to write a SQL and aspx server side.